# How to get width of view from AttributeSet if width is defined as MATCH_PARENT in XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view which I am using in Activity's XML file. The width and height of view is MATCH_PARENT. Now I am trying to fetch the width and height at run time from AttributeSet.

```
        int[] attrsArray = new int[]{android.R.attr.layout_width, android.R.attr.layout_height};
        TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray);
        int width = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        int height = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

But it is crashing. 
The logger output is -

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x10
 System.err:     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:572)
```

I can understand that as it is not MATCH_PARENT is not dimension that is why it is crashing so how can I get the width and height?

Comment: You're question is a little unclear. Are you trying to get the `View`'s actual dimensions, or, do you just want to know if it's `MATCH_PARENT`?

Comment: I want to get the actual dimension of view.

Comment: The `View` won't really have dimensions until it's laid out, at which point you can use `getWidth()`/`getHeight()`. You won't be able to get those in the constructor, though, and you can't get them from the attributes. You could override the `onSizeChanged()` method, as that will fire when the dimensions are actually set; they're passed into that method as the first two parameters.